# Is it possible to power three external drives from a RPi 5?

Tags: pi-5

I'm looking to make a small NAS with a pair of external SSDs in a RAID1 configuration, and a NVME drive for the OS. I already have the drives, so I'm trying to put them to good use.

My question is if I can accomplish this with only a RPi 5 and the official power supply, without factoring in a powered USB hub - which I'm trying to avoid due to space reasons.

The problem is that the power consumption tables that I can find around are wildly different, and I don't know which to trust.

Apparently, the situation is like this:

- A NVME drive requires from `3.5W` up to `8.5W` or more with a peak above `10W` for high-end drives.

  - My drive is an older one, I got from a laptop, the label on it reads `3.3V`/`1.1A` - does that mean less than `4W`?
- A SATA SSD drive will usually be below `4W` maximum power consumption.

  - I have two, so that means less than `8W` total for both of them.
- The Pi itself would consume up to around `12W` peak power consumption.

That would sum up to a total of:
`1 x 4W` + `2 x 4W` + `12W` = `24W`

That would be the peak power consumption, and still below the maximum power output of the official power supply, which outputs up to `27W` of power.

Considering that the Pi itself will rarely be at peak load (if ever), that seem to be more than enough power to even have a small safety margin.

Am I wrong somewhere? Should I take into account more margin for error?

Comment: keep in mind that max usb power draw is still limited to 1.6A. I'm sure that I have seen reports by users that 2 USB SSDs could cause power problems

Comment: *"more margin for error"* -> Yeah: *"the Pi itself will rarely be at peak load (if ever)"* Okay, so there is absolutely no reason to use an external drive for the OS (but since you already have the drives, you are welcome to try it).  Also, presuming the drives are not ancient in terms of capacity, if you really really want it run off a USB device just add a 50-100 GB partition to one of the SSDs (actually 2 partitions, but the first one can be tiny, a 100 MB).  That's plenty.  This will also free you up from some of your space constraints.

Comment: @Dirk that would be 1.6A per USB port or controller?

Comment: That's 1.6A total for all USB ports. see https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi-5.html#powering-raspberry-pi-5 `f the Raspberry Pi 5 firmware detects a supported 5A-capable supply, it increases the USB current limit for peripherals to 1.6A, providing 5W of extra power for downstream USB devices, and 5W of extra onboard power budget.`

Comment: That settles it then, a powered USB hub it is. Please post this info as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: Would someone **please** put this in the form of an answer??